# UITableViewCell not intercepting scroll events

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableView in which some cells have a `UICollectionView` in them (for horizontal carousels). It works great for every cell except for one in which the tableView can't be scrolled (either in simulator or on device). To be more exact, the scroll is possible if the touch occurs on the `UICollectionViewCell`, but not if it occurs on the portion of the `UITableViewCell` that doesn't contain the `UICollectionVIew`.

I'd like to find out why that is, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. Is there a breakpoint, maybe a symbolic breakpoint, that I can set to understand where the touch events go?

I tried printing stuff in these 3 methods (from the cell itself) to see how and when they were called, but there are not called.

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool 

override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool 

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

I am not sure posting code is relevant. It's a complex view with lots imbricated parts. I'd rather prefer any debugging technique that would be helpful in this situation.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

Here's more precisions:

There are no other gestures than the ones of the `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

My view hierarchy is like this:

```
|--- UITableViewCell --------------|
|-|---cell's content view -------|-|
|-|-|---container view --------|-|-|
|-|-|-|---labels ------------|-|-|-|
|-|-|-|---collection view ---|-|-|-|
|-|-|-|----------------------|-|-|-|
|----------------------------------|
```

The container view inside the cell's content view has its purpose. But I feel like it is that view that block the scroll gestures.

Apart from `isUserInteractionEnable = true`, is there anything else that could block gestures events to go up the superviews? This container view doesn't have any gestures attached to it.

Comment: Without posting code, it's hard to tell where your gestureRecognizers are placed, etc.   That said, I'd review [cancelTouchesInView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624218-cancelstouchesinview) if you've got gesture recognizers in play.   Perhaps setting it to false for one of them will let the touch fall through.  Also check that you aren't tapping on a label or something that has `userInteractionEnabled = false` set.

Comment: In senerios like this were you want a all touches from a "containing" view to affect one of its subviews you have to handle the gestures on the "containing" view (your UITableViewCell) and pass the events along to your subview (your UICollectionView). Something like this should help https://medium.com/@nguyenminhphuc/how-to-pass-ui-events-through-views-in-ios-c1be9ab1626b

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added more precisions to the question, hoping it adds clarity. @AllenR, the blog post is nice, but it talks about communicating gestures to subviews. It points me to a good direction of checking if the gestures are passed along to superviews. I should also point out that the solutions in the post didn't help... And none of these views have userInteractionEnabled = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work by changing the background color of the container view from .clear to some gray.

I'm confused that it works, because transparent views (color: .clear) are supposed to participate in the event responder chain. But that being said, everything was set to .clear, from the container view to the tableView. So the color that was displaying was the viewController's background color.

I'm not sure if it was a bad setup on my part or a bug in UIKit, though. I'd guess it's on me? Anyway... I'm leaving this here in case somebody else runs into this issue.